# OpenLayers 3+: highlight some kilometer in the map

Tags: openlayers

I want to highlight some kilometer of measured activity in the map.

This is my try with [ol.style.FlowLine](https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/style/map.style.gpxline.html):

`onmouseover='show_km(i, starttime, endtime)'`

...

```
function show_km(km, stime, etime){

    show_this_km = km;
    window.stime = stime;
    window.etime = etime;
    var show_km = new ol.layer.VectorImage(
    {   source: source,
        style: style_show_km,
        name: "show_km"
    });
        map.addLayer(show_km);
}
```

```
function style_show_km(f) {
    return new ol.style.FlowLine({
      color: function(f, step){
        
    var blue = [0, 0, 255, 0.35];
    
    var seg = [];
        var line = f.getGeometry().getLineString(0);
        line.getCoordinateAtSeg(step*line.getLength(), seg);

    return (typeof stime !== "undefined" && typeof etime !== "undefined" && seg[0][3]>=Math.round(stime) && seg[0][3]<=Math.round(etime) ? blue : "transparent");


      },
      width: 3,
      geometry: function (f) {
        if (f.getGeometry().getType() === 'MultiLineString') {
          return f.getGeometry().getLineString(0);
        } else {
          return f.getGeometry();
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

It works but position of the kilometer will change when I zoom in the map. Where's the problem? Maybe exists some simpler solution for highlight of kilometers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `visible` style option to `false` to calculate on the whole line and not only on the visible part...

```
return new ol.style.FlowLine({
  visible: false,
  color: ...
```

You can also use a standard stroke style with a geometry function to extract the part of the line to display...